How to fix dead Android logo with stomach open blue squares?
I'm trying to do a hard reset on a Q Link Scepter 8 tablet, but the dead Android sign comes on with an open stomach with blue little squares.
How do I fix this?

What steps have you performed to perform a hard reset? Based on your description the image you see should be like in this article https://techbeasts.com/android-recovery-mode/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
